# Jenkins: extract artifacts from another build job given parameters

Tags: jenkins

I would like to use the artifact of another build job in Jenkins. I have several parameters used to select which build I want.

For example, I have the parameter **a,b,c** and they are defined in **Project A**, the build name is set as **#{BUILD_NUMBER}|a|b|c**. Now I am working in **Project B** and want to extract the artifact (the file or link both ok) from the most recent successful build in Project A that matches the parameter **a,b,c**.

Is it possible to achieve this?